# pandas decoding a string returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, decode

I'm practicing on the kaggle news headline dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/aaron7sun/stocknews#Combined_News_DJIA.csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/Combined_News_DJIA.csv')
```

When read the DataFrame of news headline, I get this off formatting of the series:

```
0       b"Georgia 'downs two Russian warplanes' as cou...
1       b'Why wont America &amp; Nato help us? If they w...
2       b'Remember that adorable 9-year-old who sang a...
3       b' U.S. refuses Israel weapons to attack Iran:...
4       b'All the experts admit that we should legalis...
```

I tried using the following:

```
df['Series'].str.decode("utf-8")
```

However the output is a list of `NaN`. Any ideas? Would be great to implement on the whole DataFrame and not just one Series.

Comment: so, u want to apply ```str.decode``` on entire dataframe instead of just specified column ?

Comment: entire dataframe. Tried on a series first.

Answer (score 6):

You can't decode it from UTF-8 because it's already a string - not a byte-sequence.

The content of the file is indeed confusing: it contains strings that start with `"b'...`, which misleads the use to thinks it's bytes - but it's not.

If you run `df.Top1[0]`, you'll see that it contains:

```
'b"Georgia \'downs two Russian warplanes\' as countries move to brink of war"'
```

And `type(df.Top1[0])` is just a string. Therefore - you can't decode it from UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion how I can clean the strings then?

Comment: @ohoh7171 You can trim it using [`strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)  - `df.Top1.str.strip("b\'\"")`